# How do I understand the gradient for complex functions that do not satisfy the Cauchy Reimann Equation

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, complex-numbers

Let us suppose that my function is
(z : C -> C)

```
z = x - i*y
```

now here the real part is,

```
u(x, y) = x
```

the imaginary part is,

```
v(x, y) = -y
```

so, when we get the derivatives, we find

```
d_u_x(x,y) = 1 # derivative of u wrt x
d_u_y(x,y) = 0
d_v_x(x, y) = 0
d_v_y(x, y) = -1
```

so, here,

```
d_u_x != d_v_y
```

thus, it does not follow Cauchy Reimann equation.

but, then comes the Wirtinger calculus, that says, I could write my function as,

```
u(x, y) = ((x + iy) + (x - iy))/2
        =  (z + z.conj())/2
v(x, y) = (((x + iy) - (x - iy))/2i
        = (z - z.conj())/2i
```

but what after this, how do I find the gradient.
plus, in PyTorch, what is the correct way to specify such a function,
if I do,

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(1, dtype=torch.cfloat, requires_grad=True)
f = a.conj()
f.backward()
print(a.grad)
```

is this a correct way?

Answer (score 0):

You may find the following page of interest:

> - When you use PyTorch to differentiate any function `f(z)` with complex domain and/or codomain, the gradients are computed under the assumption that the function is a part of a larger real-valued loss function `g(input)=L`. The gradient computed is `∂L/∂z*` (note the conjugation of `z`), the negative of which is precisely the direction of steepest descent used in Gradient Descent algorithm. Thus, all the existing optimizers work out of the box with complex parameters.
> - This convention matches TensorFlow’s convention for complex differentiation, but is different from JAX (which computes `∂L/∂z`).
> - If you have a real-to-real function which internally uses complex operations, the convention here doesn’t matter: you will always get the same result that you would have gotten if it had been implemented with only real operations.
>
> ...
>
> For optimization problems, only real valued objective functions are used in the research community since complex numbers are not part of any ordered field and so having complex valued loss does not make much sense.
>
> It also turns out that no interesting real-valued objective fulfill the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So the theory with homomorphic function cannot be used for optimization and most people therefore use the Wirtinger calculus.

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/autograd.html